# Why is the exec option not listed in /proc/mounts?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

My understanding is `/proc/mounts` should list all mount options for a filesystem, including kernel defaults, so I was surprised to see that exec (among others) is not listed here?

For example, my root and home filesystems in fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/vg0-xen_root  /      ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
/dev/mapper/vg1-xen_home  /home  ext4  defaults                   0  2
```

and how they appear in /proc/mounts:

```
/dev/mapper/vg0-xen_root /     ext4 rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/vg1-xen_home /home ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered                  0 0
```

The filesystem independent defaults documented in `man mount`:

```
defaults
    Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
```

Why are some defaults (e.g. `rw`) listed but others (e.g. `exec`) are not?  Is there a way to get the complete set of mount options associated with a filesystem?

Comment: man mount has a good list. But induvidual filesystem can define their own flags -> there is a separate list for every filesystem. But there are common flags and they are listed on the mount manpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in `/proc` are generated by the kernel, not by the `mount` utility. The kernel omits options that are in their default kernel setting. The defaults of the `mount` utility don't always match the kernel defaults. You can check the defaults for your kernel version in the source code, in [`fs/proc_namespace.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc_namespace.c?v=3.15). For example, as of version 3.15, [`noexec`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc_namespace.c?v=3.15#L64) is displayed if applicable; nothing is displayed in the no-`noexec` (i.e. `exec`) case.

Comment: ahh that explains it. that source also shows that 'rw' is resolved and printed separately, explaining the difference there as well

Answer (score 3):

The reason is probably that `exec` is the opposite of `noexec`, and it is `noexec` that is listed. Thus if `noexec` is absent, the user knows that `exec` is in effect. This is similar to `dev` / `nodev`. It seems that the exception is `rw`, which is listed even though it is in the default list.

Note: while the mount(8) man page says that `defaults` is a fixed list of default options, the [fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) Wikipedia page says that "Default settings are defined per file system at the file system level."

Comment: you pretty much nailed it. I went with Gilles answer just because he also included the source that definitively shows this logic.

Answer (score 2):

`man mount` has a good list. But induvidual filesystem can define their own flags -> there is a separate list for every filesystem. But there are common flags and they are listed on the mount manpage.

`exec` is a default flag. The list of the defaults mount flags are also in the man mount (AFAIK in the kernel sys_mount() syscall there is no such thing). But if you will disallow it, you need to use `noexec`.